# how to clear textbox when it first comes into focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clear a textbox when it first comes into focus and that's all.  I can clear the textbox whenever it comes into focus but this is turning into a problem.  I just want it to clear when it first comes into focus.

So when the page loads, the textbox says "search here" -- once the user clicks inside, "search here" disappears and the textbox goes blank.  The user can keep typing their search query.

But my code, as seen below, just keeps clearing the textbox.  Any ideas?

```
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('')
});
```

Comment: I would test the value against the default value on focus - while also blanking out if value is default - so that you appear to give the user a default without actually providing content. Also, your 'input[type=text]' is capturing way too many matches to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This clears the default text on focus and puts it back in on blur.  If a new text is typed in different then default value, it no longer clears the input. Test it out by clicking outside and input few times. Then type in new text and do the same.

```
$('.text').focus(function() {
    if (this.value == this.title) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $(this).val(this.title);
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/32Tns/4/

Comment: I would have voted this the answer too, since this is how I would have approached it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isFirst = true;
 $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      if(isFirst){
        $(this).val('');
        isFirst = false;
       }
});
```

Try this. The code only delete only the first occurrence of focus.

Comment: genius!  thank you.  i really need to think outside the box with this stuff :/

Comment: The selector in this case is criminal. Guaranteed to cause problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do this once, then you won't need the event handler anymore after executation. So removing the event handler would be the best practice and perfomant way.

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(event) {
    $(this).val("").unbind(event);
});
```

This is better, because you won't create an overhead by defining additional variables or DOMNodes and the event is deleted as you won't use it anymore.

Aside from that we suggest you using a different selector, because you will apply this event for evey textinput on your site. And it's very likely, that you don't want this. I recommend you using an id selector (`input#id`) or class selector (`input.class`) to clearly identify this special textinput.
So you'll endup with:

```
$("input.clearOnFocus").focus(function(event) {
    $(this).val("").unbind(event);
});
```

---

I suppose, that you want to do something similar to the search bar on the top of this page. What you're doing is semantically not correct. Look at [this](http://www.zurb.com/playground/inline-form-labels) for real **inlined labels**.

Comment: His question was about only firing the event once. I don't kow, what your exact problem with this is.

The question wasn't about "best selector and event binding practices".

Comment: Reedited my comment, hadn't finished and accidentally pressed enter.

Comment: Read my comment - read again and consider your answer more carefully.

Comment: Ok - First of all, you didn't even spell `focus` correctly, and second of all, selecting every `input` of type 'text' is just... wrong. You don't need to be "simply answering the question" to recognize that's not the right answer.

Comment: Happy Easter, you've just found a typo. What's wrong with `type=text`?

Comment: You should point out that it's wrong and suggest a better way, ie, classing or some other selector method. :)

Comment: Nope, it isn't. What about password or file? And aside from that, I just copied @ysrb 's selector. It is possibly that he's using a totally different selector and just choosed this selector for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Uh yeah it's patently not right. Imagining the OP is smarter than your answer is not the answer, either. Maybe they have not/do not notice the problem. Fix it, don't argue with me (someone commenting your answer).

Comment: Ok, you're right - Didn't see your last comment as I posted my last.

Comment: You're making progress. Just a hint, you can edit and improve the OP's content, as long as you can explain why you did so. You don't need to be shy if you feel you are right - if you are not, someone will point out any issues, which will improve your insight going forward.

Comment: Thank you Jared. And thank you for your patience. I'm sorry. ;)

Comment: No worries, no reason to apologize. We've all been there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers that have been published solve the problem.
Now I'm posting another one that make use of the useful jQuery function "one".

[Jquery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element.

```
//Limpiar campos input la primera vez que se entre
//Cleaning input fields first time they get focus
$('input[type=text]').one("focus", function() {    
        $(this).val("");
});
```