# onBlur - restore input values after onfocus clear

Tags: jquery, input, getelementbyid, onblur, onfocus

I have several input fields with values dynamically inserted. Below a simplified example:

```
<input id="amount1" type="number" onfocus="" oninput="update()"
<input id="amount2" type="number" onfocus="" oninput="update()"
<input id="amount3" type="number" onfocus="" oninput="update()"
```

Values are inserted using:

```
document.getElementById("amount1").value = Amount1;
document.getElementById("amount2").value = Amount2;
document.getElementById("amount3").value = Amount3;
```

After a user clicks on the input field, the value is cleared, but if nothing is entered then I would like onblur to restore the value. Haven't been able to find a solution in Javascript or Jquery.

Comment: Sounds like you want a placeholder

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input id="amount1"  placeholder="Amount1" type="number" onfocus="this.placeholder = '';"  onblur="this.placeholder='Amount1'" oninput="update()"/>
<input id="amount2"  placeholder="Amount2"type="number"  onfocus="this.placeholder = '';"  onblur="this.placeholder='Amount2'"oninput="update()"/>
<input id="amount3"  placeholder="Amount3" type="number" onfocus="this.placeholder = '';"  onblur="this.placeholder='Amount3'" oninput="update()"/>
```

Just copy the code. it will work surely

Comment: Roshni, thank for your answer. Placeholder doesn't work for my situation as I need to perform calculations with the values.

Comment: Clarify your question so i cn help you better

Comment: Roshni, using the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8ywj03se/1 (with Martin's code from reply above) I would like the following to happen.

When a user clicks on the input field the field should clear, but when the user doesn't enter anything and moves away from the field, the original value should be restored.

The input values are generated dynamically, depending on what users are entering in other areas in my application.

Comment: okay that means you want to retain last value entered when user moves out of the textbox?? @dean2020

Comment: Correct, I just found a solution using jquery and title attribute (Hussein's answer works for me).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527292/how-to-clear-textbox-when-it-first-comes-into-focus

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in the element's `data-` attribute.

```
<input id="amount1" type="number" onfocus="focus(event)" oninput="update()" onblur="blur(event)">
```

Store the original value:

```
function focus(e) {
    var elm = $(e.target);
    elm.data('orig-value', elm.val());
    elm.val('');
}
```

Then restore the value on `onblur` event:

```
function blur(e) {
    var elm = $(e.target);
    if (!elm.val()) {
        elm.val(elm.data('orig-value'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reply! I put the code in a fiddle, but it doesn't seem to behave as expected. The field does not clear onfocus. https://jsfiddle.net/8ywj03se/1/

Comment: You need to tell jsfiddle specifically that you use jQuery and it'll include it for you. See: https://jsfiddle.net/4dgkspt9/1/